# openstreetmap (OSM) same map display window after update

Tags: android, openstreetmap, android-mapview, osmdroid

Maybe this is a duplicative question, but I can not find the answer.

I use osmdroid and show a route with geopoints. This route updates if a new GPS-Location is availably. But with this update the scale, zoom and center is not the same any more.

I tried to use projection but can't get a solution.

```
projection = mapView.getProjection();
```

...

```
                        if (projection==null) {
                        mapView.getController().setZoom(14);
                        mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)); //You should select a point in your map or get it from user's location.
                    }else {
                        mapView.getController().setZoom(projection.getZoomLevel());
                        mapView.getController().setCenter(projection.getBoundingBox().getCenter());
                    }
```

What is the right way to show the same map display window after the update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I post the answer for all people who have the same problem.

It is very simple: Do nothing. if you add or modify an overlay of the mapview do not change the mapview itself. 
Initialize the zoom and center of the map for example in the onCreate method. And do the drawing of the overlay in another method. If you call this drawing method again you now not changing the zoom and center.

that's it.